# How to run OpenCv in electron via emscripten / wasm

Tags: opencv, webpack, electron, emscripten, webassembly

I am trying to get opencv.js running inside of electron. The problem it seems is that webpack is giving up on the size of the library, it just get's stuck and does not finish.

Unfortunately I could not find any example demonstrations of these technologies (electron, webpack and opencv).

Any help to make this work is greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe you will find this useful: https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv-electron

Comment: @Oliort this is not useful because it uses a native module (opencv4nodejs) which is not really useable in electron. Have been trying for weeks to make this run, without success